# Is it possible to do this build this query with Dapper?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, dapper

Is it possible do do the following? I tried, but when it got to the Query, it just said there was a null reference.

```
   var builder = new StringBuilder("select * from my table1 where 1 = 1");

if(x==1)
    builder.Append(" and x = @x");

if(y==2)
    builder.Append(" and y = @y");

// when it gets here, it just says null reference

 db.Query<table1>(builder.ToString(), new {x,y});
```

I got SqlBuilder to run in .net 3.5, but when I do this:

```
var builder = new SqlBuilder();

var sql = builder.AddTemplate("select * from table /**where**/ /**orderby**/");

 builder.Where("a = @a", new { a = 1 })
        .OrWhere("b = @b", new { b = 2 });
```

I expected `select * from table WHERE a = @a OR  ( b = @b )`

but I got:

I expected `select * from table WHERE a = @a AND  ( b = @b )`

Comment: Please quote the entire error message.

Comment: I don't see anything immediately wrong there; do you have a stack-trace from the exception?

Comment: @MarcGravell - Sorry Marc, I originally typed this on my phone and don't have the original error message.  If x and y are not empty or null, it works, but if I only specify one of them, it throws an error.  I am using .NET 3.5 of SqlMapper.

Comment: Well, it isn't something I've seen. I can look, but a stack trace would really help

Comment: Are you sure db is non-null?

Comment: @MarcGravell - I will update my post with something I got working, but it is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably this was due to [this bug](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/573). The attempted fix was made on Jul 31 2016 however [there are still issues](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/647) with this approach. The plan is that this would be fixed in the next major release.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create that dynamic condition **using [DapperQueryBuilder](https://github.com/Drizin/DapperQueryBuilder/)**:

```cs
var query = cn.QueryBuilder($@"
    SELECT * 
    FROM Table
    WHERE 1=1
");

if(x==1)
    query.Append($"and x = {x}");

if(y==2)
    builder.Append($" and y = {y}");

var results = query.Query<YourPOCO>();
```

**The output is fully parametrized SQL (`WHERE 1=1 AND x = @p0 AND y = @p1`).**

Disclaimer: I'm one of the authors of this library