# Dapper SqlBuilder OrWhere using AND instead of OR

Tags: dapper, sqlbuilder

I was trying to use the Where and OrWhere methods of SqlBuilder for Dapper, but it is not acting like how I would expect.

The edited portion of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29156948/is-it-possible-to-do-this-build-this-query-with-dapper) is basically what I ran into. Since it didn't receive a response, I'll ask it here.

```
var builder = new SqlBuilder();
var sql = builder.AddTemplate("select * from table /**where**/ ");
builder.Where("a = @a", new { a = 1 })
        .OrWhere("b = @b", new { b = 2 });
```

I expected `select * from table WHERE a = @a OR b = @b`

but I got `select * from table WHERE a = @a AND b = @b`

Is there any way to add an OR to the where clause using the SqlBuilder?

I think it's just a matter of changing the following in the SqlBuilder class to say OR instead of AND, but I wanted to confirm.

```
public SqlBuilder OrWhere(string sql, dynamic parameters = null)
{
    AddClause("where", sql, parameters, " AND ", prefix: "WHERE ", postfix: "\n", IsInclusive: true);
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nevermind. I looked through the SqlBuilder code and found that if there is a mixture of Where and OrWhere, it will do the following:

- Join all the AND clauses
- Join all the OR clauses separately
- Attach the OR clauses at the end of the AND clauses with an AND

If you don't have more than 1 OrWhere, then you won't see any OR.

I'll modify my query logic to take this into account

Comment: So how does your solution look? I stumbled over this issue, too and after looking through the source-code of SqlBuilder i wonder if nesting ORs and ANDs works somehow in sqlbuilder: (... OR ...) AND (... OR ...) vs. (... AND ...) OR (... AND ...)

Comment: From what I remember, it seems to work this way. (... AND ... AND ... AND ( ... OR ... OR ... OR)). It will put all the ANDs together and then put the ORs at the end in their own group

Comment: I have two OrWheres and two Wheres. I don't see any ANDs in the generated query, only ORs.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change your query into:

```
var builder = new SqlBuilder();
var sql = builder.AddTemplate("select * from table /**where**/ ");
builder.OrWhere("a = @a", new { a = 1 })
        .OrWhere("b = @b", new { b = 2 });
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to try another alternative, **[DapperQueryBuilder](https://github.com/Drizin/DapperQueryBuilder/)** may be easier to understand:

```cs
var query = cn.QueryBuilder($@"
    SELECT * 
    FROM table 
   /**where**/
");


// by default multiple filters are combined with AND
query.FiltersType = Filters.FiltersType.OR; 

int a = 1;
int b = 2;

query.Where($"a = {a}");
query.Where($"b = {b}");


var results = query.Query<YourPOCO>();
```

**The output is fully parametrized SQL (`WHERE a = @p0 OR b = @p1`).

You don't have to manually manage the dictionary of parameters.**

Disclaimer: I'm one of the authors of this library

Comment: I'm looking forward to giving DapperQueryBuilder a go some time. It looks great, well done. Is it easy to see what the generated SQL is whilst debugging?

Comment: @Zac yes, if you hover the mouse over "query" you should see the underlying query and the attached parameters.